# Drupal 7 Vieuws: Grouping terms with content

Tags: drupal-7, view

I have a taxonomy vocabulary that goes like this:

**TERM A**

-- Term 1

---- Term 1a

---- Term 1b

-- Term 2

---- Term 2a

---- Term 2b

**TERM B**

Now for example I have in **Term 1a** : 5 nodes
and in **Term 1b**: 3 nodes

I would like a view that shows this:

**TERM A (as a title)**

Term 1 (2 fields) but only from 1 node

Term 2 (2 fields) but only from 1 node

**TERM B (as a title)**

...

I tried it with Grouping fields but then I get a result like this

---- Term 1a

---- Term 1b

? I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create 2 views.

The first will return your Terms list (View Terms) and, the second will be included into the other one with Conditionnal Filter (with Term Reference).

On this post https://drupal.org/node/1197752, users explain this trick.

Hope it's usefull for you :)